# Setting supported interface orientation as 'All' only MPMoviePlayerController is active in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation, mpmoviewcontroller

I am trying to set interface orientation only `MPMoviePlayerController` is active. Meanwhile, a movie started to play. In the target of the project, I have checked `Portrait`, `Landscape Left` and `Landscape Right`. Also, in the AppDelegate file, I have implemented `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` method and I tried to check `presentedViewController` is a `MPMoviePlayerController`. However, I could not implement it correctly. 
How can I solve my problem with the correct way ? 
What is the best solution changing supported interface orientation when MPMoviePlayerController is active ?

Thank you for your answers

King regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`  **only** for `MPMoviePlayerController` so, while creating the controller use a `BOOL` variable to identify interface needed or not .

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
```

Override the `initWithContentURL` method and set AppDelegate BOOL variable to `YES`and at `viewWillDisappear` set the BOOL to `NO`.

In Appdelegate.m

```
#pragma mark --- Orientation Changes for Movie

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{

if (self.OrientationNeeded)
{
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

The flow will be perfect ,first your init method is called and you have setted BOOL variable and then `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` method is called and revert BOOL back when view is out.